# activity insert using rest api

Tags: activities, call-center

I am trying insert an Activity object from an external telephony system after a call is made however I am not seeing an API to call the Activity Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Activity` is an odd pseudo-object that represents the common core of fields shared between the `Task` and `Event` objects. `Activity` is where you create custom fields in Setup that are available on both the `Task` and `Event`.

[`ActivityHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm) is a read-only summary object.

You can't directly create either. Instead, create either a `Task` or `Event` (as appropriate; your use case sounds like a `Task`). The system will handle building the `ActivityHistory`.

Comment: thanks I think the best way is to use the Event Object for this I am using Bright Pattern for my call center and there App Exchange package has some custom fields to support this in the Event Object